# How to get field's type annotation in Java Annotation Processing?

Tags: java, annotations, preprocessor, annotation-processing

For example, I have this code:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
public @interface ClassAnnotation {
}

@ClassAnnotation
public class AnnotatedClass {
}

@ClassAnnotation
public class AnotherAnnotatedClass {

    private AnnotatedClass someField;
    private int intIsNotAnnotated;
}
```

And this processor to preprocess it in compile time:

```
@SupportedAnnotationTypes({ "com.example.ClassAnnotation" })
@SupportedSourceVersion(SourceVersion.RELEASE_6)
public class AwesomeProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {

    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations,
            RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
        // Skipped for brevity...
        // For each annotated class
        for (Element e : roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(ClassAnnotation.class)) {
            // Skipped for brevity...
            // For each field
            for (Element ee : classElement.getEnclosedElements()) {
                // Skipped for brevity... (of course there's kind checking)
                TypeMirror fieldType = fieldElement.asType();
                TypeElement fieldTypeElement = (TypeElement) processingEnv.
                    getTypeUtils().asElement(fieldType);
            }
        }
        // Skipped for brevity
    }
}
```

I need to check whether a field's type is a class that is annotated with my annotation. Somehow I've got a `TypeElement` named `fieldTypeElement`, it may represent `AnnotatedClass` from `someField` or `int` from `intIsNotAnnotated` in the example. How to get `@ClassAnnotation` of `AnnotatedClass` of `someField`? I've tried `fieldTypeElement.getAnnotation(ClassAnnotation.class)` and `fieldTypeElement.getAnnotationMirrors()`, but it returns null and empty list respectively.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are somehow getting the wrong `TypeElement` but unfortunatly that part of the code is missing.

This simple example works as expected:

```
processingEnv.getElementUtils().getTypeElement("AnnotatedClass").getAnnotationMirrors()
```

contains `@ClassAnnotation`.

To get the `TypeElement` of a field, you'll have to

1. get the fields's type
2. cast the type to `DeclaredType`
3. get the declared type's element
4. cast the element to `TypeElement`

The last step isn't necessary though to get an element's annotations:

```
Element field = // ... 
List<? extends AnnotationMirror> annotationMirrors =
    ((DeclaredType) field.asType()).asElement().getAnnotationMirrors();
```

---

The updated code should work, I've tested it and it runs fine. The error must be elsewhere. Some other things to check for:

- Make sure the build is good, sometimes a build step fails and old code is used unnoticed
- Check the `RetentionPolicy` of the annotation. None, `CLASS` or `RUNTIME` are fine but `SOURCE` won't work

Comment: I've added more code to show how I get `TypeElement` in my question

Comment: @BornToCode I've updated the answer. If it still doesn't work I'm out of ideas for now.

Comment: Oh, you're right. I used `SOURCE` retention. The question is updated to show retention policy. But I'm still curious why it didn't work, annotation processing is at *source* phase instead of *runtime*, doesn't it?

Comment: @BornToCode You can still access the source files at the point when annotation processing happens, but when working with the java.lang.model api you already have a more abstract representation of the source code. I think _source_ is for the compiler (or anything that reads the raw source files) only.

Answer (score -2):

Iterate through the `Field`s on the `Class` and check whether the type of each field contains the annotation.  To get the type of the `Field` use the [Field#getType](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getType%28%29) method.  From the provided pseudo code it appears you have access to the `Field`s.

**Processor.java**

```
public class Processor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Class<?> clazz = AnotherAnnotatedClass.class;
        Field[] fields = clazz.getDeclaredFields();

        for(Field f:fields){
            if(f.getType().isAnnotationPresent(ClassAnnotation.class)){
                System.out.println(f.getName());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**ClassAnnotation.java**

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface ClassAnnotation {

}
```

**AnnotatedClass.java**

```
@ClassAnnotation
public class AnnotatedClass {

}
```

**AnotherAnnotatedClass.java**

```
@ClassAnnotation
public class AnotherAnnotatedClass {

    private AnnotatedClass annotatedClass;
    private int intIsNotAnnotated;
}
```

Comment: I am sorry, I am not asking about Java Reflection in runtime, but [Java Annotation Processing](http://deors.wordpress.com/2011/10/08/annotation-processors/) in compile time.